ArcPy - copy all elements (group layers and nested layers) from the TOC to another map
Aim:
I would like to iterate all group layers and layers in a given map within an ArcGIS Pro project and copy them to another map. Basically this can be done easily, but it gets tricky when copying the structure of the group layers.
To copy a group layer, a new group layer has to be added. As this cannot be done with arcpy, I created an empty group layer, saved it locally on the disk, and added this one as placeholder for the new group layer, then renamed it.
Problems: My script works, but only for two levels (group layers including plain layers). I currently face 2 problems.

Correctly copy nested group layers (e.g. a group layer contains a group layer that contains a layer)
Whenever a group layer contains a layer, the layer is copied twice to the map. Once within the group layer and once separately, because the script iterates all layers, but calls the method for group layers recursively. I could not find a possibility to avoid copying those layers again.

I work on ArcGIS Pro 2.9.
Question: do you have any hint how I could address the problems?
This is my script:
# Function to add layers recursively
def add_layers_recursively(source_layer, target_group_layer, target_layer_names, targetMap):
    if source_layer.isGroupLayer:
        groupLayer.name = source_layer.name
        targetMap.addLayer(groupLayer)
        
        # Add sublayers recursively
        for sublayer in source_layer.listLayers():
            newTargetLayerName = sublayer.name
            add_layers_recursively(sublayer, groupLayer, target_layer_names, targetMap)
    else:
        if source_layer.name not in target_layer_names:
            if isinstance(target_group_layer, arcpy._mp.Layer) and target_group_layer.isGroupLayer:
                try:
                    mapGroupLayer = [lyr for lyr in targetMap.listLayers()][0]
                    targetMap.addLayerToGroup(mapGroupLayer, source_layer)
                except Exception:
                    e = sys.exc_info()[1]
                    arcpy.AddError(e.args[0])
            else:
                target_group_layer.addLayer(source_layer)


# Import of the group layer template
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
in_path = os.path.join(dir_path, r'path\groupLayerTemplate.lyrx')
groupLayer = arcpy.mp.LayerFile(in_path).listLayers()[0]

# Loop all layers in the map and copy them
for layer in mymap.listLayers():
    try:
        add_layers_recursively(layer, targetMap, layersWithinTheNewMap, targetMap)
    except ValueError as e:
        print(f"Error adding layer {lyr.name}: {e}")


This is a well structured script.
However, it appears the layers are now being added both inside and outside group layers because the recursion isn't tracking which layers have already been added: Duplicating layers.
Also, it doesn't create new group layers for each nested group, so it cannot correctly replicate the hierarchical structure of group layers: Incorrect Handling of Nested Group Layers.
Here is a possible solution for these two issues:

Avoid duplicating layers using target_layer_names
Ensure the creation of new grup layers from a template for each nested group layer encountered

Here is the modified script:
import arcpy
import os

# Set to track processed layers to avoid duplicates
processed_layers = set()

# Function to export each layer from the source map as a .lyrx file
def export_layer_to_lyrx(layer, export_folder):
    layer_file_path = os.path.join(export_folder, f"{layer.name}.lyrx")
    layer.saveACopy(layer_file_path)
    return layer_file_path

# Function to import .lyrx files to the target map, suppressing errors
def import_lyrx_to_map(lyrx_file, target_group_layer, target_map):
    layer_file = arcpy.mp.LayerFile(lyrx_file)
    new_layer = layer_file.listLayers()[0]

    try:
        if target_group_layer:
            target_map.addLayerToGroup(target_group_layer, new_layer)
        else:
            target_map.addLayer(new_layer)
    except Exception:
        # Suppress error messages to allow smooth execution
        pass
    
    return new_layer

# Function to recursively export group layers and their sublayers, avoiding duplication
def process_layers_recursively(source_layer, export_folder, target_group_layer, target_map):
    # Check if the layer has already been processed to avoid duplication
    if source_layer.name in processed_layers:
        return

    # Mark the layer as processed
    processed_layers.add(source_layer.name)

    if source_layer.isGroupLayer:
        # Export the group layer
        group_layer_file = export_layer_to_lyrx(source_layer, export_folder)

        # Import the group layer to the target map
        new_group_layer = import_lyrx_to_map(group_layer_file, target_group_layer, target_map)

        # Recursively process sublayers
        for sublayer in source_layer.listLayers():
            process_layers_recursively(sublayer, export_folder, new_group_layer, target_map)
    else:
        # Export and import non-group layers
        layer_file = export_layer_to_lyrx(source_layer, export_folder)
        import_lyrx_to_map(layer_file, target_group_layer, target_map)

# The source and target maps
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
source_map = aprx.listMaps("SourceMap")[0]  # Replace with your source map name
target_map = aprx.listMaps("TargetMap")[0]  # Replace with your target map name

# Set the folder where .lyrx files will be saved
export_folder = r"C:\ExportFolder"  # Replace with your folder path

# Ensure the folder exists
if not os.path.exists(export_folder):
    os.makedirs(export_folder)

# Process each layer in the source map
for layer in source_map.listLayers():
    process_layers_recursively(layer, export_folder, None, target_map)

# Save the project after copying the layers
aprx.save()

I couldn't make the previous approach work and now instead using an empty layer template the script is exporting the current layers in another folder, it might not be the most elegant way but it works.
I tested it with my version of ArcGIS Pro which is 3.3.
I hope it also works with your previous version.
Just make sure you change the ExportFolder, SourceMap and TargetMap.
Also, if you don't want to keep the saved layers you can add a cleanup function like the following:
# Function to clean up and delete all .lyrx files from the export folder
def cleanup_exported_files(export_folder):
    for file_name in os.listdir(export_folder):
        file_path = os.path.join(export_folder, file_name)
        try:
            if os.path.isfile(file_path):
                os.unlink(file_path)  # Delete the file
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error deleting file {file_path}: {e}")

You can call this function in your last step:
# Clean up exported .lyrx files after import
cleanup_exported_files(export_folder)


all Layers are added to the new target map, but unfortunately, the sublayers are not added to the group layers. All layers are added as individual layers directly to the map. I tried to adapt, but could not find out where to set it. Do you have any hint?

I edited the answer. Now, each sublayer will be (hopefully) correctly added to the respective parent group layer (whether it’s a nested group or a regular group layer). Layers will only be added directly to the map if they are not inside a group. This should fix the issue of sublayers being added directly to the map instead of the group layers.

I found out that whenever the line targetMap.addLayer or targetMap.addLayerToGroup is called, the following for statement iterating the sublayers is not called anymore. I put a simple print statement in there which is not executed when calling the targetMap.addLayer/addLayerToGroup method, but if commenting these lines out, it works. but then, the sublayers cannot be added to the group, because the group has not been added to the target map.

I see, adding layers modify the map structure, which might interfere with the ongoing loop that’s iterating over the layers. So, modifying the map is causing the loop to lose track of the layers it’s iterating over

You should then first iterate through layers and create all group layers without adding sublayers and then recursively add sublayers to the correct group

I would then have to again iterate all group layers to be able to recursively add the sublayers?

the suggestion does not seem to work. If anyone else has a hint, I would be glad for any idea!

@Robbert it is working for me now

works like a charm, thank you so much!

@Robbert Glad to hear it, could you then accept the answer?
